# SQL Multiple Case When and mulitple results

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a sql query that simplified looks like this:

```
declare @Method varchar(max);
set @Method = 'phone'

select
case 
    when @Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumber is not null and u.PhoneNumberConfirmed = 1 then u.PhoneNumber
    when @Method = 'email' and u.Email is not null and u.EmailConfirmed = 1 then u.Email
end,

case 
    when @Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumberSecondary is not null and u.PhoneNumberSecondaryConfirmed = 1 then u.PhoneNumberSecondary
    when @Method = 'email' and u.EmailSecondary is not null and u.EmailSecondaryConfirmed = 1 then u.EmailSecondary
 end
```

So this displays it in 2 columns. I want all the results in only 1 column. I could split it up with union like this:

```
...
select
case 
    when @Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumber is not null and u.PhoneNumberConfirmed = 1 then u.PhoneNumber
    when @Method = 'email' and u.Email is not null and u.EmailConfirmed = 1 then u.Email
end 

from
...

union

select

case 
    when @Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumberSecondary is not null and u.PhoneNumberSecondaryConfirmed = 1 then u.PhoneNumberSecondary
    when @Method = 'email' and u.EmailSecondary is not null and u.EmailSecondaryConfirmed = 1 then u.EmailSecondary
 end
```

But the problem is then that it could be that it doesnt exist any rows with PhoneNumberSecondary and then I get a NULL row.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Add a check in the where clause of the second query for `PhoneNumberSecondary` or `EmailSecondary`?

Comment: If you give the whole query I'll supply an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `UNION` is the right way of doing it. If you need to get rid of `NULL`s, add a `NULL` check, for example, to the outer query:

```
SELECT contact_info
FROM (
select
case 
    when @Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumber is not null and u.PhoneNumberConfirmed = 1 then u.PhoneNumber
    when @Method = 'email' and u.Email is not null and u.EmailConfirmed = 1 then u.Email
end as contact_info
from ...
UNION
select
case 
    when @Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumberSecondary is not null and u.PhoneNumberSecondaryConfirmed = 1 then u.PhoneNumberSecondary
    when @Method = 'email' and u.EmailSecondary is not null and u.EmailSecondaryConfirmed = 1 then u.EmailSecondary
 end as contact_info
from ...
)
WHERE contact_info IS NOT NULL
```